# Running a python script via cron at a random time between 10AM-11PM once every day

Tags: ubuntu, cron, scheduling

I'm on ubuntu and need to run a python script once every day randomly between 10AM-11PM. Right now I've only got it running at a fixed hour, I've seen a few examples but mostly for repetitive tasks within a timeframe, whereas I need just once per day.

Any ideas on what the best approach would be?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of `cron` supporting a Random start time.

But you can make use of `at` to schedule your `python` script to run at a random time:

```
0 10 * * * echo '"/path/to/my_script.py"' | at "now + $(shuf -i 1-780 -n 1)min"
```

This has the benefit compared to my previous solution using `sleep`, that it will be kept between reboots.

You can check with `atq` at which time the job is scheduled.

Comment: is it not a problem to lock cron execution for several hours ?

Comment: I'm not aware that `cron` executions are locked from other running `cron` processes. Just made a test, and that is not the case.

Comment: @Kiwy  cron launches jobs in the background. You can launch 100 jobs "at once" and they will all get started withing a very few seconds of the start time. The sleep is part of the job, not part of the cron execution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cron at all. [Systemd timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#RandomizedDelaySec=) have a built-in option for this, called `RandomizedDelaySec`:

```
RandomizedDelaySec=
   Delay the timer by a randomly selected, evenly distributed amount of time between 0
   and the specified time value. Defaults to 0, indicating that no randomized delay shall
   be applied. Each timer unit will determine this delay randomly before each iteration,
   and the delay will simply be added on top of the next determined elapsing time, unless
   modified with FixedRandomDelay=, see below.
```

So, in your case, you'd have a timer with `OnCalendar=*-*-* 10:00:00` and `RandomizedDelaySec=46800` (=13 hours). See [this post on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1083537/158442) or [the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Timer) for more details on setting up systemd timers.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule the job for 10:00 every morning, and have the job sleep for a random amount of time, between 0 seconds and 46800 seconds.

The only catch here is that we can't do `sleep "$(( RANDOM % 46800 ))"` since the shell's `RANDOM` variable (in the case of `bash` at least) takes values between 0 and 32767, which is too small.

Instead, we may use `awk`,

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN { srand(); print int(46800*rand()) }'
```

Which means we could use the following schedule:

```
0 10 * * * sleep "$( awk 'BEGIN { srand(); print int(46800*rand()) }' )" && mypythonscript
```

---

Another approach is to use the `RANDOM` variuable anyway, but to get *minutes* rather than seconds from it.  The time span that you're interested in is exactly 780 minutes, so you could use

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

0 10 * * * sleep "$(( 60*(RANDOM % 780) ))" && mypythonscript
```

This means your python script would only start on a full minute, unless you use `RANDOM` *again* to randomize the `60` above as `(RANDOM % 60)`.

Comment: This was also my first approach, but if you shutdown or reboot at any time while sleeping, the script won't run.

Comment: @pLumo Sure, it depends on circumstances what approach they want to take. If this is a system in a server hall that shuts down only for physical maintenance, once in a blue moon, then they may want to prioritize simple over smart.